# how to count multiple shortest path in undirected graph.Edges doesn't have weight

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

[image: network with s as a source vertex and t as a destination vertex]

Question: find the total number of shortest paths between nodes s and t.

Edges doesn't have weight so we can't use dij. algo. I know how to apply bfs but unable to make count of different paths

Comment: @templatetypedef this is related to undirected graph. So please remove the tag duplicate from it

Comment: can you show me an example how to apply because I am new to all this